# Used the Same DNS address in Google Domain and Google Cloud but cannot view website

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

I have my Domain name through Google Domain and I have set up my website on Google Cloud.  But I cannot get to my website.

I used the same DNS servers for in Google Domain/DNS/Google Named Servers and Google Cloud/Network Services/Cloud DNS  Type NS.

ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com

Can you tell me if this is correct?

Thank you

Comment: It's important you create your managed zone to your Cloud DNS - can you provide a little more detail about it's configuration (DNS records) ?

Comment: I think the problem is fixed.  When I first tried to connect Google Domain with Google Cloud, I change the Google Cloud DNS to match the Google Name Domain DNS.  That did not work.  But when I change the Google Cloud DNS back to what it was at the start and change the Google Domain DNS to match what I had in Google Cloud it worked  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you share some screenshot or configuration of your Cloud DNS for this domain ? You can do it with `gcloud dns managed-zones describe my_zone`. It would be more benericial for the community.